# Dropdown centered underneath parent with overflow: hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a nav bar which has a string of text for a link that opens a dropdown. The parent of this link has `overflow: hidden` to allow me to truncate the string incase it gets too long. However, I want the dropdown to be positioned absolutely underneath and centered regardless of the width of the parent. Since I'm using `overflow: hidden`, the dropdown gets cutoff. I want to keep the positioning of the dropdown as well as the `overflow` properties.

Is there a CSS fix for this? I know I can't ignore the parent's `overflow` property, but I'd rather not use `position: fixed` and manipulate margins with JavaScript if possible.

I've made a simple fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/berryboy/goqegnwh/)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *" I want to keep the positioning of the dropdown as well as the overflow properties."* No CSS solution that I'm aware of. Perhaps another method of truncating the string?

Comment: Were my answer useful? ... other ways is i.e. to re-structure your html and either move the text out of your `inner` or set `overflow: hidden` to the text instead of its parent.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way in CSS to make a child of an overflow: hidden element show its contents outside the parent borders, you must change the hierarchy.

If that is not possible, you could add padding at the bottom to .nav-pull-left that is the size of your dropdown, although that's a rubbish solution..

```
.nav_pull_left {
  width:auto;
  height:50px;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
  overflow:hidden;
  float: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

You could also use JavaScript to dynamically update the height of your parent container when the dropdown shows but once again, reordering the hierarchy is best and cleanest.

If that is the way you want to go, let me know and I can help :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think if I have to go the JavaScript route, then I'm just going to position it however I need using `position: fixed` and call it a day. I'll keep you posted!

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest the following, where you change your css as follows.

```
.nav_pull_right {
  min-height:50px;      /* changed height to min-height */
  ...
}

.nav_pull_left {
  min-height:50px;     /* changed height to min-height */
  ...
}

.my_dropdown {
  position: relative;  /* changed absolute to relative */
  margin: 0;
  margin-left:-87px;
  /* top: 2em; */      /* removed top */
  left: 50%;
  width: 170px;
  z-index: 99999;
  border:2px solid #929292;
}
```

With this your container overflow is kept and gets pushed down, the drop down menu is centered.

Is this something you could use?

Here is a [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/goqegnwh/9/)